# Find a simple form for the EGF (in terms of $f(x)$)

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, exponential-function, generating-functions

For a sequence $(a_n) = (a_0 ,a_1, ...)$ supposed that $f(x)$ is its EGF (Exponential Geneterating Function). For each of the following sequences, find a simple form for the EGF

For a sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2,...),$ its EGF is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$

1. $(0,a_1, a_2,...)$
2. $(a_1, a_2,...)$
3. $(0,0,1,a_3,a_4,...)$
4. $(a_0,0,a_2,0,a_4,0,...)$

I am completely lost because I keep getting 0=0 or something along those lines.
For something like #1, I have

$A(x) = 0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!} = (-a_0 + a_0) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!} = -a_0 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$

$A(x) = -a_0 + A(x)$

This is where I'm lost

Comment: how would i do #4? i'm not sure what I add to f(-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the same function symbol $A$ for both generating functions. On the right you should have replaced the complete series by $f(x)$, not $A(x)$, yielding the correct result $A(x)=f(x)-a_0$.

For #$2$, you can shift the sequence by taking the derivative.

I think #$3$ will be clear from #$1$.

For #$4$, consider $f(-x)$ and how you might combine it with $f(x)$ to get rid of the odd-numbered terms.

Comment: for #3, i have A(x) = e^x + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}an\frac{x^n}n!. How would i index the series? It looks like f(x) but n starts from 3

Comment: @pop: How did $\mathrm e^x$ get in there?

Comment: Oh, i thought when a_2 = 1, we get the series x^n/n! which was e^x.

Comment: @pop: I'm afraid I don't understand where you got that idea from. $1$ takes the place of $a_2$; there's no reason for any of the other terms of that series to appear.

Comment: Would it be A(x) = 1 + $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}an\frac{x^n}{n!}$? I'm not really sure how to implement the sequence into the EGF, that is where I get things mixed up.

Comment: @pop: No. You substituted $1$ for $a_0$ instead of $a_2$. Also, I believe the idea of the exercise is to write things in terms of $f(x)$, not as a separate series. It's really just the same thing you did for #$1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107862/discussion-between-pop-and-joriki).

Comment: @pop: No, sorry, I don't want to take this much time for that. I think you're missing some basics about generating functions that you should go back and catch up on.